# Process.Start not working on UAT for opening file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod, process.start

this works on dev as usual when I put it on UAT the code does something different. A PDF is saved on the server, the class then opens it up using the url of that file. 
The URL works fine if I paste it into a browser, but doesn't work from the code.
Here's my code:

```
  Process.Start(openPath);
```

openPath will look like: "http://www.cbm360.net/test/temp/CBM360Report_1093750.pdf"

The file is there on the server, but it just won't open in the code. 
The code is inside a web method called using AJAX, if that makes any difference, I'm not sure.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this isn't working?

The Exception is:

```
 System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are the operating systems identical?  What is the path you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pasting the URL into a browser (I assume this is on the server), try it directly from the command line on the server. Does it work now? Process.Start is not the same as navigating to a URL in the browser, it is more akin to running the URL from the command line. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Normally we would use a web request to get a pdf.